Memcpy specified bound exceeds maximum object size - gcc bug?
I'm getting a very weird warning when trying to compile Fribidi with gcc. Take a look at the following line:
memcpy (visual_str, str, len * sizeof (*visual_str));

(source)
It triggers this gcc warning:
In function 'fribidi_log2vis':
fribidi.c:245:7: warning: 'memcpy' specified bound between 18446744065119617024 and 18446744073709551612 exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Wstringop-overflow=] memcpy (visual_str, str, len * sizeof (*visual_str));

What on earth is this please? len is a variable that is unknown at compile time so how on earth does the compiler complain about bounds exceeding the maximum object size?
Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something here?
The compiler is gcc 13.1.0 on MSYS2.

Are you sure that there isn't a path through the code where len remains undefined at runtime? That might explain the compiler blowing up although the msg could be clearer. Does -Wall shed any light?
